# How to connect to Office 365 mailbox using redemption

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio, outlook-redemption

I want to connect to office 365 using redemption and download all the emails from the inbox and from other folders, my development machine is

- Windows 10 X64
- Visual Studio 2015 Pro
- Outlook is not installed on my development machine
- Installed **Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1** from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1004)
- Used this command to register redemption.dll in my form1.cs file `regsvr32.exe <fullpath>\redemption.dll`
- Refrenced Interop.Redemption.dll in my project

**This is the code I am trying to connect to Office365 mailbox**

```
  string codeBase = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

            RedemptionLoader.DllLocation32Bit = string.Concat(path, @"\Redemption.dll");
            RedemptionLoader.DllLocation64Bit = string.Concat(path, @"\Redemption64.dll");

            RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();

            session.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox("smtp.office365.com", "abc@domain.com","xxxx");// getting error at this line               

            if (session.LoggedOn)
            {
                RDOFolder contactsFolder;    
                contactsFolder = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
                var i = contactsFolder.Folders.Count;

                foreach (var item in contactsFolder.Folders)
                {
                    var obj = (RDOFolder2)item;
                    var name = obj.AddressBookName;    
                }
            }
```

This is the error I am receiving

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   ErrorCode=-2147023541   HResult=-2147023541   Message=The specified
>   domain either does not exist or could not be contacted
>   Source=Redemption.RDOSession   StackTrace:
>          at Redemption.IRDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(String SMTPAddress, String UserName, String Password)
>          at Office365Backup.Form1.CreateSession() in D:\Data\Projects\DotNet\Office365Backup\Source\Office365Backup\Form1.cs:line
>   40
>          at Office365Backup.Form1..ctor() in D:\Data\Projects\DotNet\Office365Backup\Source\Office365Backup\Form1.cs:line
>   19
>          at Office365Backup.Program.Main() in D:\Data\Projects\DotNet\Office365Backup\Source\Office365Backup\Program.cs:line
>   25
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Any advice to successfully acomplish this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to an Office 365 mailbox (or any mailbox on Exchange 2013 or 2016), you will need the Outlook version of MAPI (Outlook 2010 SP2, Outlook 2013 SP1, or Outlook 2016) - the standalone version of MAPI cannot connect as Exchange will refuse the connection.

Also note that the first argument in `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` is the SMTP address of the user, not a server name.

Comment: Are you saying that he is using the standalone version and he needs to use the Outlook version of MAPI? Did you get that from his statement that Outlook is not installed on his development machine?

Edit: Also, Does the MAPI Client mean stand alone?

Comment: @Dmitry, what do you mean by Outlook version of MAPI you mean I need to install Outlook 2013 or 2016 or is there anything else which I need to install, sorry couldn't get what you are trying to suggest.

Comment: Yes, I would need to install Outlook. That will install the MAPI system.

Comment: @Maderas - yes. Also the link is to the old version of MAPI. The latest one is from 2014: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42040